# How to configurate on kubernetes to update from git repository?

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, cloud, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I just installed bitnami/wordpress image using helm. Is it possible to sync it with git and when I will change some files in this git repository to update kubernetes pods?

I mean update Wordpress source code because Im modyficating plugins in wp-content/plugins dir.

Comment: Do you mean when you update your WordPress source code?

Comment: @DonDonDon, did you find the solution?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak today I will try to check solutions from users

Comment: Do you have any progress?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak just now still working on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to use [git-sync](https://github.com/kubernetes/git-sync) in a `sidecar` container. It will periodically pull files down from a repository and copy them to a volume.

Here is a sample manifest which uses git-sync to update the content hosted on a simple nginx web server:
[https://github.com/nigelpoulton/ps-vols-and-pods/blob/master/Multi-container-Pods/sidecar.yml](https://github.com/nigelpoulton/ps-vols-and-pods/blob/master/4%20-%20Multi-container%20Pods/sidecar.yml)

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to use it to installation from bitnami/wordpress for example? Because in git repository I want to have only files from wordpress, not full image.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ArgoCD](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [Flux](https://fluxcd.io/) to automate this types of GitOps workflow. Check their documentation. They are pretty powerful and popular for GitOps in Kubernets.

Comment: I installed ArgoCD (with flux I had some problem on windows). Is it possible to connect it with current bitnami/wordpress applicaion or only one dir inside it? @EmruzHossain

Answer (score 0):

One way I managed it (although possibly a rookie way) was through github actions.

[Here's an example of mine](https://github.com/ZOrfeas/saas-15/blob/main/.github/workflows/ms-auth-CI.yml)
[And here's official docs from docker to configure with github actions](https://docs.docker.com/ci-cd/github-actions/)
You basically want to tell github actions to recreate and push your image and then tell your cluster to refresh like so:

If you're using `kubectl` to manage your cluster check if your version supports `kubectl rollout restart`. You can use it to force any deployment to restart and smoothly recreate your pods (it also re-pulls the supporting image).
e.g.: `kubectl rollout restart deployment/my_deployment`